# Call onAcitivityResult in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android

I pass a parameter from a second activity to the first activity but the program doesn't enter the method onActivityResult that is in the first activity and it doesn't anything.

In my first Acitivity I have 2 clases.
The first one I do a query and I call the second class ListAdapter:

```
public class view_records extends Activity {
   public void getProduct() { 
   comandSQL = "Select * from Inventario";      
   try {
    Statement statement = MainActivity.connect.createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery(comandSQL);
    ArrayList<product_model> product_list = new ArrayList<product_model>();
    String tidno = "", tdesc = "";
        while(rs.next()){  
            tidno = rs.getString("No_");
            tdesc = rs.getString("Descripción Completa");
                product_model _ProductModel = new product_model();
             _ProductModel.setIdno(tidno);
             _ProductModel.setProductDesc(tdesc);
             _productlist.add(_ProductModel);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
    }
```

} 
`

In the Second Class I call a second activity

```
private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    int request_code = 1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modelo_productos, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.txt_prod = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_productos);
            viewHolder.txt_desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_prod.setText(_productlist.get(position).getIdno().trim());
        viewHolder.txt_desc.setText(_productlist.get(position).getProductDesc().trim());

        final int temp = position;

        (convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_modificar)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        modificarProd(temp);
                    }
                });
        return convertView;
    }


    protected void modificarProd(int temp)
    {
        String pos = Integer.toString(temp);

        String _productid = String.valueOf(_productlist.get(temp).getIdno());
        String _productdesc = _productlist.get(temp).getProductDesc();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), modificar_productos.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", _productid);
        bundle.putString("desc", _productdesc);
            bundle.putString("pos", pos);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivityForResult(intent, request_code);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (RESULT_OK == request_code){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("pos");
            _productlist.remove(result);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     }

}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_desc;
    Button btOK;
    int position;
}
```

}

And this is part of the Second Activity

```
public class modificar_productos extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
String pos;
double costo;
Intent i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.modificar_productos);

    i = getIntent();

    tvProd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_prod);
    tvDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);

            tvProd.setText(i.getExtras().getString("id"));
    tvDesc.setText(i.getExtras().getString("desc"));
    pos = i.getExtras().getString("pos");
    btGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_guardar);
    btGuardar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bt_guardar:
        if (etCant.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(modificar_productos.this, "Por favor, ingrese la cantidad",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

          Intent data = new Intent();
          data.putExtra("pos",pos);
          setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
          finish();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong condition:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (RESULT_OK == request_code){ <--- here
     ...
    }
 }
```

Should be:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (RESULT_OK == resultCode){
     ...
    }
 }
```

The requestCode is the code you start your activity with: `startActivityForResult(intent, request_code)`, so you can use it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch (requestCode) {
        case request_code:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // do your stuff here 
            }
        break;
    }
 }
```

**Edit 1**: you have to put `onActivityResult` method into `view_records` `Activity` class. The `ListAdapter` is initiated in `view_records`, so it will deliver the result to this Activity.

**Edit 2**: refreshing adapter

```
public class view_records extends Activity {

  ListAdapter mAdapter; // create adapter handler

  public void getProduct() {
    // ...
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      switch (requestCode) {
          case request_code:
              if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
          break;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi!! I tried but it doesn't work :(, I saw in some examples that the method have @override and I'm not able to do that.

Comment: You can't use `onActivityResult` in ListAdapter class. It has to be used in Activity class with @Override. Put `onActivityResult` into `view_records` Activity

Comment: It works!! But... I have to refresh my adapter and I call it from ListAdapter class...

Comment: You can refresh adapter in `onActivityResult` method, check **Edit 2**.